# PHP include statement, excessive double dot

Tags: php

I find myself writing a ton of these include statements:

```
<?php
require '../../../../engine/my_file.php';
```

This double dot syntax becomes quite confusing, especially when there are a lot of double dots.

This project is built and deployed via its own Github repository... is there a way to set some kind of project root in PHP? Something that I could use in the following way:

```
<?php
require project_root.'/engine/my_file.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
define('project_root', Your path);
```

Comment: Don't I have to set this definition in every file that I want to use `../../../../engine/my_file.php`?

Comment: If you have a config file ... define it and use it across all pages

Comment: If your application is object-oriented then try the PRS-4 Autoloading Standard